# Hi, i have an assigment to sum all the digits of a number in one line using lambda and map in python

Tags: python, error-handling, iteration

In addition i can't convert int to string both ways and can't use list comprehension

I keep getting the same error and i don't know how to deal with it...

This is the code:

```
sum_of_digits = lambda a: map(lambda b, c: b + sum_of_digits(c) if a > 10 else None, a % 10, a / 10) if a > 10 else None

def main():
    print(sum_of_digits(104))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the error:

```
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

Comment: Second argument of `map` must be some sort of sequence (or iterable to generate sequence) of objects to which one by one the function in `map`s first argument is applied.

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Well, it is syntactically correct and throws no error. This doesn't mean it makes much sense.

Comment: @MichaelButscher then its fine

Answer (score 1):

(This answer was for a previous version of the question but does not meet the requirements of the new, edited version.)

As others have pointed out, the cause of your error is that the second parameter to your `map` function is an integer, `a % 10`, but it is supposed to be an iterable.

Here is a one-liner that satisfies your problem requirements: it creates a function that returns the sum of the digits of a non-negative integer, and uses both `lambda` and `map`. It also uses `int` and `str` but that does not go against your stated requirements. This works because `str(a)` returns a string, which is an iterable of the digits of the number. Each digit is a 1-character string, which must be converted to an integer before summing. The `map` does that conversion.

```
sum_of_digits = lambda a: sum(map(int, str(a)))
```

Comment: I forgot to inform that i can't convert it between int and string and can't use list comprehension as part of the assignment.

Comment: @MichaelCracker: That is a major change to your question. You really should have asked a new, separate question, adding those new requirements. I'll leave this answer for reference but note that it does not answer the new version of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Map takes a function and applies it over some iterable thing. You haven't given it an iterable thing, just a function.

Try something like this

```
import math

sum_of_digits = lambda x: sum([int(c) for c in str(x)])

the_value_of_a_specific_digit = lambda x, d: int(x / 10 ** d % 10)
an_iterable_of_number_of_digits = lambda x: range(int(math.log(x, 10))+1)
a_combined_function = lambda x: sum(map(func, iterable))

def main():
    print(sum_of_digits(104))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I forgot to inform that i can't convert it between int and string and can't use list comprehension as part of the assignment.

Comment: OK, that makes it harder. I've edited the answer to give you some ideas for how you might go about this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fun little recursive version using `and`:

```
sum_of_digits = lambda n: n and n%10 + sum_of_digits(n//10)
```

If `n` is falsy (i.e. zero) it returns `n`, otherwise it returns the sum of the least significant digit and `n//10`

If you're using Python 2, you'll have to `from __future__ import division`

Comment: That's a pretty neat one. Haven't seen that before.

Comment: nice,it even works without importing from __future__. can you try helping me with my line of thought?

Comment: I think this is more readable as `sum_of_digits = lambda n: n if (n < 10) else (n % 10) + sum_of_digits(n // 10)`. It also runs one less call deep for arguments with a non-zero ones digit.